# FB login with different account some permission(user_photos) doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I made website using facebook API. I set API's live features available to the general public to "YES". the problem is facebook content show me everything when I use my FB account ID. But when I login with different account then some permission(user_photos) doesn't work. I submit the API submission but they didn't reviewed yet. On submission time I have added user_photos item. So What should I do for different account.

Comment: _"I submit the API submission but they didn't reviewed yet"_ - well then obviously you have to wait until your app has been reviewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long answer short: As of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review it's not possible to use extended permission for non-admin/developers/testers of an app as long as it hasn't passed the review.

Otherwise the review would be useless IMHO. So, I'm afraid you have to wait until the review process is finished.